# I can't create and write a table even though I connect my code to mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to create a user login system with mysql, but I can't add users, it doesn't write data to the table.

```
#my code

if secim == "2":
        name = input ("adınız")
        lastname = input ("soyadınız:")
        username = input ("kullanıcı adınız:")
        password = input ("Şifreniz:")
        search =search_username(username)
        if search != None:
            print("bu kullanıcı adı ile zaten hesap var")
            continue
        insert(name, lastname, username, password)
        print("kayıt başarılı")
        if secim == "3":
            break

#my server connection

def insert(name, lastname, username, password):
    baglanti = pymysql.connect(host='host',
                               user='user',
                               password='password',
                               db='db',
                               charset='utf8mb4',
                               cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor = baglanti.cursor()

    komutekle = """INSERT INTO USERS(name, lastname, username, password) VALUES {}"""
    data = (name, lastname, username, password)

    cursor.execute(komutekle, data)

    baglanti.commit()
    baglanti.close()
```

Under normal circumstances, when I choose the 2nd option, it would ask me for my name, surname, username, password, but after entering them, it gives an error.
this is the error

```
not all arguments converted during string formatting
  File "C:\Users\erpstajyer\Desktop\geleceğe dönüş\mysqlserver.py", line 42, in insert
    cursor.execute(komutekle, data)
  File "C:\Users\erpstajyer\Desktop\geleceğe dönüş\hesap kısmı.py", line 59, in <module>
    insert(name, lastname, username, password)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: There are no placeholders in your SQL statement.

Comment: Your query `komutekle` has no placeholders `%s`.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the arguments like: VALUES(%s, %s, %s), where the %s quantity is the argument quantity in insert statement.

Code in a recommended way:

```
baglanti = pymysql.connect(host='host',
                               user='user',
                               password='password',
                               db='db')

with baglanti.cursor() as c:
    komutekle = """INSERT INTO USERS(name, lastname, username, 
    password) 
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"""
    data = (name, lastname, username, password)

    cursor.execute(komutekle, data)

    baglanti.commit()
    baglanti.close()
```

Using format:

```
with baglanti.cursor() as c:
    komutekle = """INSERT INTO USERS(name, lastname, username, 
    password) 
    VALUES ({}, {}, {}, {})""".format(name, lastname, username, password)

    cursor.execute(komutekle)

    baglanti.commit()
    baglanti.close()
```

passing arguments with %s avoids SQL injection.